# Index and apply an attribute to an element by values in an array with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add a rel attribute of the element matching the array, so for example the array is:

```
var targetVal = ['1','2','4'];
```

And 5 elements with the same class:

```
<a class="link" href="1.html">
<a class="link" href="2.html">
<a class="link" href="3.html">
<a class="link" href="4.html">
<a class="link" href="5.html">
```

I want to target the 2nd, 3rd and 5th line with a rel attribute.

```
 $(".link").each(function(index) {
       $(this).attr("rel", "group");
    });
```

How can I make the above script index through based on the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var targetVal = ['1','2','4'];

$.each(targetVal, function(index, val) {
       console.log(val);
       $('.link').eq(val).attr("rel", "group");
});
```

jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/T7zR8/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over your array, and [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the link at a specific index:

```
var $links = $(".link");
$.each(targetVal, function(value) {
    $links.eq(value).attr("rel", "group");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more optimal, only evaluating the set of links once, and directly accessing that list instead of using `.eq()`:

```
var targetVal = [1, 2, 4];
var links = $('.link');
$.each(targetVal, function(i, n) {
    links[n].setAttribute('rel', 'group');
});
```

or, on newer browsers, and without jQuery:

```
var targetVal = [1, 2, 4];
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
while (targetVal.length) {
    links[targetVal.pop()].setAttribute('rel', 'group');
}
```